# Does the format on jquery's Datepicker stay as "MM/DD/YYYY" no matter the geographic location?

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I know that input[type="date"] is localized depending on browser/location. So if the date displays as YYYY/MM/DD on my computer, it could display as DD/MM/YYYY on another computer, and this is a result I must avoid. So I was thinking maybe jquery's Datepicker may resolve this. The Datepicker's format is MM/DD/YYYY on my computer, but will this *also* be the default format on another person's computer (that is from a different geographic location and/or browser language setting)? If so, how would I set the Datepicker's default format to MM/DD/YYYY so that it would override the geographic location/browser language setting on other computers?

Comment: Please read: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ > Additional Notes: *Creating a datepicker on an `<input type="date">` is not supported due to a UI conflict with the native picker.*

Answer (score 0):

You can set the date format on the jqueryui datepicker i.e.

```
 $( '#yourelementid' ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',    
});
```

i.e. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQasn.jpg